# Display HTML content in UIView Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

I have an issue with displaying HTML Content in UIView.
Following is my HTML response from a service

```
EmpTable = "<table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='8' bgcolor='#d4d4d4'><tr><th>Employee</th><th>Designation</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></tr><tr><td>Work Place</td><td>Emp Join Date</td><td>10-09-2009</td><td>17:06</td></tr><tr><td>Emp Attendance</td><td>Emp Id</td><td>11-09-2017</td><td>17:05</td></tr><tr><td>Employee</td><td>Employee Name</td><td>11-09-2017</td><td>09:04</td></tr><tr><td colspan='4' align='RIGHT'><span style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: xx-small;'><strong><span style='color: red;'>*</span>\U00a0- 24 Hrs Format<br /><br /></strong></span></td></tr></table>";
```

Don't have any idea how to display the same HTML response in UIView. Please find some help to slove the issue.TIA

Comment: Heard of webView ?? Thats all you need not UIView

Comment: @Rajeev use Web view to display HTML content

Comment: Using WebView will resolve your issue i believe. @Rajeev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Webview or you can try UITextView.

```
NSAttributedString * str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

textview.attributedText = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UIView` you should use `WKWebView`. Below is simple example of how to use `WKWebView`.

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // change frame that you need 
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl]; // you can set here HTML content too.      
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

For more information you can read [this tutorial.](https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/implement-wkwebview-in-ios/)